# How can I include a link instead of attachment in Freeform Pro email?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm using the File Upload field type in one of my web forms. The email notifications include the uploaded file as an attachment. Is there any way to change this to a download link? My reason is that most of the file uploads are too large for email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

Add the Freeform field tag: `{freeform:field:file}` to your form and choose the directory you wish the files to be uploaded to.

Go to your notification settings in Freeform and add the {file} tag inside (swap file for your file field name).

Make sure the **Include Attachments** checkbox is unticked and hit save.

Now when you get notifications they should just contain the file name.

To make it the full URL you can use the following:

`{site_url}[path-to-upload-directory]/{[field_name]}`

example:

`{site_url}uploads/documents/{file}`

This should then link directly to your newly uploaded file. If you tick **Enable HTML** too you could wrap them in an anchor and provide a link title

`<a href="{site_url}uploads/documents/{file}">Download File</a>`

Comment: I'm glad it helped Howard and feel free to mark the answer as accepted. Not only does it give myself a little boost it'll help if anyone else has an issue similar to this in the future. Cheers!